# View to Show Third Party Licenses in Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm new to Android App Development and was studying about various views. There was a particular view which caught my attention and is used in Google Play Music Android App

[image: Screenshot]

I think it is a PopUpWindow but not fully sure. How can we achieve this kind of View and customize the text inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a custom dialog my friend. Follow these steps to create your own custom dailog:

**step 1 :-> create a layout file custom_layout in res/layout folder like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="hello world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="hello world" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="hello world" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

**step :-> 2 create a dialog like this in your activity java file**

```
 Dialog custoDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    custoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);

    Window window = custoDialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    // acces you custom dialog controlss like this
    TextView tv = (TextView) custoDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perfom actions here
        }
    });
    custoDialog.show();
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend using [Including Open Source Notices](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) from Google. It's a Gradle plugin and does the job automatically for you. Add the plugin and then you just have to start the Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, OssLicensesMenuActivity.class));
```

Comment: How do this one use in a fragment

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, you can only start an Activity.

Comment: replace `this` with `requireContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty ambiguous. The actual view where the licenses are displayed, it's usually an android view called Dialog, there is a 3rd party library that simplifies the work with dialogs: [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).
Regarding licenses, there is a good library that retrieves info about the libraries used in your project: [3rd party licenses](https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries)